# Why can't you use an inline if statement to return?

Tags: php

I seems that there is a limitation to using an inline if statement in PHP when you want to return.

```
function example($Variable)
{
    ( (int) (++$Variable) == 1 ) ? return true : return false;
}

$test = example(1);
```

**Expected: `false`**

This gives an error which is strange because I have never seen this before.

> Error type : 4
>
> Message : syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN)

Can anyone explain why you cannot use the return inside an if statement like this?

Comment: `return  ( (int) (++$Variable) == 1 ) ? true : false;`

Comment: Note: ... http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Comment: You don't need `return` there. Put it before the inline if.

Comment: Now that makes so much more sense... (implied face palm for my stupidity)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ternary already returns the results. You can't return a return function.

You can make return before variable result like this:

```
function example($Variable)
{
    return ( (int) (++$Variable) == 1 ) ? true : false;
}
$test = example(1);
```

Comment: Ah, I can't believe I never noticed that. I thought there was some blatant reason this wasn't working. Appreciated - will mark when I can!

Comment: I like that word, ternary, never knew that existed. Noted. @PhiterFernandes

Comment: Yeah, ternary expression is the name for what you called *inline if statement*. :)

Comment: I'm going to use that just to mind baffle people ;) @PhiterFernandes